# Android Video Webview, weird behavior on some Android devices

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-video-player

I've developed an Android app that use webview to show Video player from Youtube.But I had a problem: my webview is different from some web browsers like Chrome, Firefox, default browser... as this below image ( my webview has dark area in top and bottom)

[image: Webview bug]

Any solution for my issues? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: paste your xml file code for more clarification

Comment: why don't you just have it launch the default YouTube app instead?

Comment: Youtube Android Api is available!

Comment: How to open this Video with Youtube Player from Webview? Video is component of Webview !

Comment: You can use the youtube api here is link https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: I have to use webview to play video player so Youtube Player can't solve my issue.Another solution, plz